# Edge で JS のキー入力のタイミングがずれる現象？

Tags: javascript, html5

ブラウザの Edge で JavaScript でキー入力を受け取る時、
たまにタイミングがおかしくなるのは気のせいなのでしょうか？

一番わかりやすい例だと、方向キーの右を押しっぱなしにして、
方向キーの上を押したり離したりすると、押したタイミングが0.5秒くらい遅くなることがあります。
他にも、押したこと自体が認識されなかったり、
もう離したキーが押しっぱなしと見做されてしまったりします。

単純に onkeydown と onkeyup でキーイベントを受け取ってフラグを書き換え、
各キーのフラグを setInterval で20ミリ秒の間隔で canvas に描画するだけのプログラムでテストしてます。

他のページでも同様の現象が発生しました。
（というより、それで気づいて調べてしてみたんです）

このような現象について、何かご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんか？

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザやJavascriptの問題ではなくハードウエアやOS関係の仕様かと思います。

キーボードの機能(仕様)に下記の2つがあります。
・押しっぱなしにした際に連打した時と同じ動作にする。(ドライバやBIOSによっては連打間隔を変更できる)
・キー入力の受付処理の速度より早くキーが連続して入力された場合、入力をバッファに貯めて順次入力の受付処理を行う。(バッファのサイズはアプリや環境等で大小の差がかなりある)

「入力がアプリケーションの速度を超えた為、遅れてキーボードバッファーから入力されている状態」が質問の状態と思われます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！　なるほど、ハードウェアの問題ですか。

Comment: いずれにせよ、今の Edge ではまともにキー入力できないですね。。。海外のサイトでも同様の現象が報告されているようですし。